# Dto class not creating mysql db table if Transient object values used

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, spring-mvc, saas

```
@Entity
@Table(name="timesheet")
public class TimeSheet extends HibernateDaoSupport implements Serializable{

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
@Column(name="timesheetid")
private int timesheetid;
@Transient
private Employee employeeName;
-
-
-

}
```

In the above code I use annotations with hibernate to create tables in mysql backend.

Table is not getting created while running this code . 
There is no exception in the console.

I have used the similar code prior to create many tables.Now its not working .

Is there anything i am missing ?
Kindly help.

Answer (score 0):

The point of Hibernate is not to create database tables, but to use them. You may ask Hibernate to create the schema for you in development, but that should be used only for quick prototyping, and certaily not on a production database.

See http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html_single/#configuration-misc-properties. You must use the `hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto` property to tell Hibernate to create or update database tables when the session factory is created.

Comment: Thanks JB Nizet! The problem was i used @Column(name="timesheetid")
private int to; and i used int from --- the problem was that hibernate is not permitting "to/ from" as variable name --- after changing names it worked..